# Why isn't the linker recognizing this class constructor?

Tags: c++, stl

I'm getting this error creating a new object with `KarateMatch new_match;` when compiling my `Driver.cpp` file with `g++ Driver.cpp KarateMatch.cpp -o output`:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"KarateMatch::KarateMatch()", referenced from:
  _main in cc5G5Ak8.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

`KarateMatch new_match;`

I can't figure out what I've done wrong, since I am using `#include <KarateMatch.h>` on both `Driver.cpp` and `KarateMatch.cpp`:

## Edit:

I've tried the code as exactly shown on my system (OS X 10.8.1), and this isn't compiling with the same error.

#### KarateMatch.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class KarateMatch{

    public:
        KarateMatch();
};
```

#### KarateMatch.cpp

```
#include "KarateMatch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

KarateMatch::KarateMatch(){
    cout << "HI";
}
```

Comment: It is a linking error.Make sure you are compiling and linking all source files.Besides `using namespace std;` in a header file is a bad practice,don't do that.

Comment: You do actually _link_ with the object file created from `KarateMatch.cpp`?

Comment: I think the compiler should be linking all the object files together while compiling them.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg see the command used for building at the top: `g++ Driver.cpp KarateMatch.cpp -o output` - I do guess here that Driver.cpp actually contains main

Comment: Have you tried reversing the order of the two source files in the g++ command? I know from library inclusions that the order can make a huge difference sometimes

Comment: Yes, I've tried reversing the order, same error unfortunately! And yes, Driver.cpp contains main.

Comment: Is the code you've presented here copy/pasted?  Or did you type it here manually?

Comment: With what compiler/platform are you working on? Some time ago I had a cryptic and obscure error that reminds me this one when compiling Win32 Windows application with entry point of console application.

Comment: gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00) on OS X 10.8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its running fine on my system g++-4.3..
i think its not the problem with KarateMatch.h and KarateMatch.cpp files.

try compiling only Driver.cpp first without including KarateMatch.h file and without creating its object .

Comment: It compiles fine without Driver.cpp.

Comment: i tried with this Driver.cpp     #include"KarateMath.h"
int main()
{
KarateMatch new_match;
return 0;
}    and its compiling fine

Comment: tried compiling only Driver.cpp ? "g++ Driver.cpp" without including new class ?

Comment: I've tried that, I'm still getting the error. For some reason the exact code you see above is causing issues.